# Remove model name from submitted form url (GET)

Tags: php, forms, yii

Here's my form

```
         <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('booster.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
                    'id'=>'listing-main-form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
                    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('site/search'), 
                    'method'=>'get',
                )); ?>

    <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:0px;border:none">
                    <label class="control-label" for="selecttype">Type</label>
                     <?php echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                            $model,
                            'prp',
                            array(
                                'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                                    'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                                ),
                                'widgetOptions' => array(
                                    'data' => CHtml::listData(Type::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'type'),
                                    'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'selecttype'),
                                ),
                                'label' => ''
                            )
                        ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
               <div id="resproperties">
                    <div class="resdv">
                    <?php echo $form->checkboxListGroup(
                        $model,
                        'rs',
                        array(
                            'widgetOptions' => array(
                                'data' =>CHtml::listData(ResourceCategory::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'res_category'),
                            ),
                           'label' => ''
                        )
                    ); ?>
                     </div>
               </div>
............
............
```

When the form is submitted, I can read all the field's data fine. But the url appears with Model[field] for each fields and looks very ugly (see below). Is there any where I can remove the model name from there?

```
index.php?r=site/search&ItemModel[prp]=1&ItemModel[rs]=&ItemModel[rs][]=2&ItemModel[rs][]=3&ItemModel[rs][]=4&ItemModel[cm] ............
```

Comment: Please show your form HTML. This will surely help.

Comment: @BrianGerhards I have added html for first couple of input fields. It's along form and rest of the fields are done more or less same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly set input name.

```
...
'htmlOptions' => array(
    'id'=>'selecttype',
    'name' => 'fieldname'
)
...
```

Also you can override CHtml and CActiveForm classes.

Answer (score 1):

In your array for each element, add

```
'name'=>'your_custom_name'
```

So...

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                            $model,
                            'prp',
                            array(
                                'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                                    'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                                ),
                                'widgetOptions' => array(
                                    'data' => CHtml::listData(Type::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'type'),
                                    'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'selecttype'),
                                ),
                                'label' => '',
                                'name' => 'customName'
                            )
                        ); ?>
```